# Why is a loop needed to change recordset in Access VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I was trying to change a value of a recordset Boolean column in Access. The code that I was using did not throw any error:

```
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

        rs.Open "select * from TABLE where field1 = '" & Me.field1 & "' AND field2 = '" & Me.field2 & "'",currentproject.connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
        rs("boolean") = True
```

However, the boolean value did not update. The `recordset.recodcount` property gives 1. This is why I thought I did not need a loop. But the record only updates if I add a loop and do not understand why this is the case.

```
 Do While Not rs.EOF
         rs("boolean") = True
       rs.MoveNext
       Loop
```

Why do I need to add a loop to update a field when there is only one record?

Comment: The trick is the `MoveNext` call, not the loop itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a loop. You just need to trigger the update.

In fact, this is only a limitation of how you set up the connection. Since it doesn't support batch updates, moving to the next record triggers the update.

If you add `rs.Update` to that first piece of code, it should just work.